# popBackStack remove all stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity. This activity has a view pager. This viewpager has five pages and these pages open a fragment in their contents. The problem occurs, for example, when I open two fragments in the first page and then open one fragment in a second page. I go back to first page. I click back button in toolbar. And I use `popBackStack()` code to remove fragment which is visible currently. 
But it removes all backstacks. How can I solve this?

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(str, 
FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

**My algorithm :**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(getSupportFragmentManager() != null){
                int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                Log.i("Fragment Stack Count : ", count+"");
                if (count <= 0) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    checkBackStack();
                }
            }
        }

        private void checkBackStack(){
            Log.i("BackStack", "Home Activity Count > 0");
            FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();
            if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                Log.i("BackStack", "Count > 0");
                for(int i = (fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1) ; i >=  0 ; i--){
                    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backStackEntry = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i);
                    String str= backStackEntry.getName();
                    Log.i("BackStack", " Name : "+str);
                    BaseMenuFragment fragment= (BaseMenuFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(str);
                    if(((ViewGroup) fragment.getView())!= null && ((ViewGroup) fragment.getView().getParent()) != null){
                        int contentId = ((ViewGroup) fragment.getView().getParent()).getId() ;
                        if(contentId == frames[viewPager.getCurrentItem()]){
                            Log.i("BackStack", "equals = true");
                            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(str, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does it enter the `if(contentId == ...)` more than once?

Comment: Also, what is `frames[]`?

Comment: and what happens if you don't use `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`?

Comment: frames array stores framelayout ids of fragments. Viewpager have five pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/renanbandeira/interactiveViewPager) can help you. I've faced this  some time ago and I found a solution.

> This is not a library, it is a demo app. I'm sorry if the structure is
>   Eclipse-like. It's been a while I did this.